# Pull specific methods from a module into the global namespace in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to pull in functions from a module to the global namespace in ruby with specifically naming the functions (aka not the entire module)?

I have a module that didn't use a module originally, and I want to move the classes/methods into a module, but still keep around a module that will have everything at the global level for compatibility. So far I have this.

```
# graph.rb
require 'foo_graph'
include foo

# foo_graph.rb
module foo
    # contents of the old graph.rb
end
```

But module `foo` is also in use in completely unrelated files and calling `include` could pull more stuff into the global namespace than I intend.

Is there a way for me to specify which functions I want to pull in with `include` or is there an alternative to do what I want?

Comment: Move the ones you want into a separate module, then only include that module into the places you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Use submodules.

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def bar_method; end
  end
  include Bar

  module Baz
    def baz_method; end
  end
  include Baz
end

# only include methods from Bar
include Foo::Bar

bar_method
#=> nil

baz_method
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `baz_method' for main:Object

include Foo

# include all methods from Foo and submodules
baz_method
#=> nil
```